# Including new elements in for:each

Tags: java, foreach

Before I start my question, i'd like to mention that i DID read up some other topics and i tried around a bit but im just really confused atm so i figured i'd just ask.

So what i wanna do is use for each through a Set and within that for each, add elements to that set and also iterate through those.
The solution I found elsewhere was the following:

```
for(Object obj : new HashSet<Object>(oldSet))
```

I tried that, however I keep missing some of the last elements i'd like to match so im not really sure if this is the right approach in the first place?

To be specific, this is basically what my code looks like:

```
for(Position pos : new HashSet<Position>(oldSet){
  for(Delta delta : deltas){
    if(board.getTokenAt(pos.plus(delta).equals(initial){
      hitList.add(pos.plus(delta);
      oldSet.add(pos.plus(delta);
    }
  }
 oldSet.remove(pos);
}
```

Again, I'd just like to know if my approach is wrong or there must be an error elsewhere in my code so i know what to look at.
Thanks beforehand!

Comment: normally, you don't modify the collection you are iterating over as it can lead to 'unwanted' results (I.e. you keep adding elements to the collection and thus end up in an infinite loop) - if you feel you must do this, try using an iterator...

Comment: An iterator will not support this behavior.  You can try using a BlockingQueue, but not with the for construct as you have it.

Comment: An iterator would only iterate over the initial set tho wouldnt it?
Also, adding to the set im iterating would result in a concurrentmodification exception afaik?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really add to a data structure while iterating over it, that is almost guaranteed to have unexpected results.

However, there is a simple enough solution to your issue. Just process each item recursively when you find that it needs to be added, and add it to a separate `List`. At the end of iteration, add everything in the `List` to the main `Set`. This avoids the issue of adding during iteration while still allowing you to to process the newly added items.

It would look something like this:

```
List<Position> toAdd = new LinkedList<>(); 
for(Position pos : oldSet){
  for(Delta delta : deltas){
    addIfGoodAndRecurse(pos, delta, toAdd);
  }
}
```

And then you can use this helper method to add the item if it meets your conditions and also recursively process added items. Note you will need to change the method signature to pass in your `board`, `initial`, and `hitList` if they are local variables. I didn't know their types or whether they were global variables or fields, so I couldn't really add them in the example.

```
private void addIfGoodAndRecurse(Position pos, Delta delta, List<Position> toAdd) {
    Position toCheck = pos.plus(delta);
    if(board.getTokenAt(toCheck.equals(initial))) {
        hitList.add(toCheck);
        toAdd.add(toCheck);
        for (Delta recursionDelta : deltas) {
            addIfGoodAndRecurse(toCheck, recursionDelta, toAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have your code, so I can't test this. The idea should work fine, but you may need to make slight modifications.

Comment: Im still processing it but I think I got the idea (kinda thinking of a solution atm, im not sure if it will work because your method doesnt completely work for what I wanna do) Ill try some stuff, if i run into some more problems ill reply again, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through new elements added to a list that you're iterating if you add them to the end of the list and iterate through it using an index and the `get()` method, *not through an Iterator*. You can also use the Set as you are doing now, but only to make sure you only add unique items to your collection.

```
List<Position> list = new ArrayList<>(oldSet);
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {  // NB list.length could be different each time
  Position pos = list.get(i);
  for(Delta delta : deltas){
    if(board.getTokenAt(pos.plus(delta).equals(initial){
      hitList.add(pos.plus(delta));
      if (oldSet.add(pos.plus(delta)))  // Check if it already exists in the list
          list.add(pos.plus(delta));
    }
  }
  oldSet.remove(pos);
}
```